# I don't understand why my 8.6 tcl version does understand a for loop like this: "for{set i 0}{$i<10}{incr i}{

Tags: tcl, synopsis-detect

I am using the tclsh interpreter and the Synopsis Primetime shell. Both are not supporting that kind of loop. is there something that I am missing here?

Thanks a lot

I am trying to perform a very standard for loop

Answer (score 1):

I think you just a syntax error. This works for me:

```
for {set x 0} {$x<10} {incr x} {
    puts "x is $x"
}
```

Outputs:

```
x is 0
x is 1
x is 2
x is 3
x is 4
x is 5
x is 6
x is 7
x is 8
x is 9
```

Comment: Yes thank you! My problem was that I did not put a space between the curly braces in "for {}{}{}" as you did.

Comment: You might want to review [the 12 rules of Tcl syntax](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm). This is #3: commands are made out of space-separated words.